# How can I mix VR-mode and 2d-mode Activities in the same Android app?

Tags: android, virtual-reality, oculusquest

I have an android app for Oculus Quest 2 that operates in VR mode with a single activity.

I would like to add a second activity that uses normal widgets instead of VR.

I know it is possible to run non-VR android apps on the Oculus Quest 2.  If I extend my application with a new non-VR activity that has the `MAIN` and `LAUNCHER` intent-filter and leave the `com.oculus.intent.category.VR` on the original activity, I can start the app and see the UI in a 2D window floating in the VR environment.

But when I `startActivity()` for the VR Activity, I see crashes in the logcat.

```
2023-08-24 10:14:49.784 27370-27784 VrRuntimeClient         com.x.project     I  UpdateEvents: HMT was mounted
2023-08-24 10:14:49.784 27370-27784 VrRuntimeClient         com.x.project     I  Client has lost focus.
2023-08-24 10:14:49.796 27370-27784 OsSdk                   com.x.project     E  error getting shared memory region, memory type: HeadTracker, failed with Status(-1, EX_SECURITY): 'request throttled'
2023-08-24 10:14:49.800 27370-27784 AudioCapture            com.x.project     I  AudioCapture::PauseAudioCapture
2023-08-24 10:14:49.801 27370-27784 OsSdk                   com.x.project     E  error getting shared memory region, memory type: HeadTracker, failed with Status(-1, EX_SECURITY): 'request throttled'
2023-08-24 10:14:49.802 27370-27784 OsSdk                   com.x.project     E  error getting shared memory region, memory type: HeadTracker, failed with Status(-1, EX_SECURITY): 'request throttled'
2023-08-24 10:14:49.802 27370-27784 OsSdk                   com.x.project     E  error getting shared memory region, memory type: HeadTracker, failed with Status(-1, EX_SECURITY): 'request throttled'
2023-08-24 10:14:49.802 27370-27784 Telemetry               com.x.project     W  [OpenXR] pose validation failure; 
2023-08-24 10:14:49.803 27370-27784 libc                    com.x.project     A  Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 27784 (Thread-2), pid 27370 (arch.project)
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (27812) for package com.x.project ----------------------------
2023-08-24 10:14:50.286 27810-27810 DEBUG                   pid-27810                            A  Cmdline: com.x.project
2023-08-24 10:14:50.286 27810-27810 DEBUG                   pid-27810                            A  pid: 27370, tid: 27784, name: Thread-2  >>> com.x.project <<<
2023-08-24 10:14:50.286 27810-27810 DEBUG                   pid-27810                            A        #01 pc 0000000001562a80  /data/app/~~7Rj4cfcqEuNaKBJTZ8lgfg==/com.x.project-BM56eOP_LGFnK7Uti4Fzdw==/base.apk (std::sys::unix::abort_internal::hd376a7a5dfef13f8+4)
2023-08-24 10:14:50.286 27810-27810 DEBUG                   pid-27810                            A        #02 pc 0000000001558ff8  /data/app/~~7Rj4cfcqEuNaKBJTZ8lgfg==/com.x.project-BM56eOP_LGFnK7Uti4Fzdw==/base.apk (rust_panic+120)
2023-08-24 10:14:50.286 27810-27810 DEBUG                   pid-27810                            A        #03 pc 0000000001558e0c  /data/app/~~7Rj4cfcqEuNaKBJTZ8lgfg==/com.x.project-BM56eOP_LGFnK7Uti4Fzdw==/base.apk (std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook::hae676ea4cb54d372+664)
2023-08-24 10:14:50.286 27810-27810 DEBUG                   pid-27810                            A        #04 pc 0000000001558b54  /data/app/~~7Rj4cfcqEuNaKBJTZ8lgfg==/com.x.project-BM56eOP_LGFnK7Uti4Fzdw==/base.apk (std::panicking::begin_panic_handler::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::h28e3779ad5029fec+200)
2023-08-24 10:14:50.286 27810-27810 DEBUG                   pid-27810                            A        #05 pc 00000000015565a8  /data/app/~~7Rj4cfcqEuNaKBJTZ8lgfg==/com.x.project-BM56eOP_LGFnK7Uti4Fzdw==/base.apk (std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_end_short_backtrace::hcc3186f99b814c53+4)
2023-08-24 10:14:50.286 27810-27810 DEBUG                   pid-27810                            A        #06 pc 00000000015588d8  /data/app/~~7Rj4cfcqEuNaKBJTZ8lgfg==/com.x.project-BM56eOP_LGFnK7Uti4Fzdw==/base.apk (rust_begin_unwind+108)
2023-08-24 10:14:50.286 27810-27810 DEBUG                   pid-27810                            A        #07 pc 0000000000ec790c  /data/app/~~7Rj4cfcqEuNaKBJTZ8lgfg==/com.x.project-BM56eOP_LGFnK7Uti4Fzdw==/base.apk (core::panicking::panic_fmt::hf634d2dad967350c+44)
2023-08-24 10:14:50.286 27810-27810 DEBUG                   pid-27810                            A        #08 pc 0000000000ec7cd8  /data/app/~~7Rj4cfcqEuNaKBJTZ8lgfg==/com.x.project-BM56eOP_LGFnK7Uti4Fzdw==/base.apk (core::result::unwrap_failed::heb325dbe9de0f88a+84)
2023-08-24 10:14:50.286 27810-27810 DEBUG                   pid-27810                            A        #09 pc 0000000000f69078  /data/app/~~7Rj4cfcqEuNaKBJTZ8lgfg==/com.x.project-BM56eOP_LGFnK7Uti4Fzdw==/base.apk (core::result::Result$LT$T$C$E$GT$::unwrap::hfaa71aa6fc424486+124)
2023-08-24 10:14:50.286 27810-27810 DEBUG                   pid-27810                            A        #10 pc 0000000000f47314  /data/app/~~7Rj4cfcqEuNaKBJTZ8lgfg==/com.x.project-BM56eOP_LGFnK7Uti4Fzdw==/base.apk (project::vr_engine::menu_exp::MenuExp::draw_inner_gl::h4b88970d936f21e9+1088)
...
```

What extra magic is required to be able to switch between 2D mode and VR mode in a single android application?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using ndk cpp by calling a native activity as following:

```
public class VRActivity: NativeActivity() {

    // This function will be called after getting into VR mode, by native cpp code.
    fun callAVRActivity() {
        val vrPackageName = "com.vrpackage.vractivity"
        packageManager
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(vrPackageName)?.let {
            startActivity(it)
            finish()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        init {
            System.loadLibrary("vrapi")
            Log.d("VRMode", "VRActivity, init after loadLibrary vrapi")
            System.loadLibrary("vrcubeworld")
            Log.d("VRMode", "VRActivity, init after loadLibrary vrcubeworld")
        }

    }
}
```

The vrcubeworld.so lib has VrCubeWorld_NativeActivity.cpp file with the following code:

```
JNIEnv* getEnv(JavaVM *vm) {
    JNIEnv *env;
    int status = vm->GetEnv((void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
    if(status < 0) {
        status = vm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);
        if(status < 0) {
            return nullptr;
        }
    }
    return env;
}
   
void callback(struct android_app* app) {
    ALOGV("VRMode, callback, app: %p", app);
    jobject vrActivity = app->activity->clazz;
    ALOGV("VRMode, callback, vrActivity: %p", vrActivity);
    JNIEnv* env = getEnv(app->activity->vm);
    ALOGV("VRMode, callback, env: %p", env);
    jclass vrActivityClass = env->GetObjectClass(vrActivity);
    ALOGV("VRMode, callback, vrActivityClass: %p", vrActivityClass);
    jmethodID callALHubDemoMethodId = env->GetMethodID(vrActivityClass, "callALHubDemo", "()V");
    ALOGV("VRMode, callback, callALHubDemoMethodId: %p", callALHubDemoMethodId);
    if (callALHubDemoMethodId != NULL) {
        env->CallVoidMethod(vrActivity, callALHubDemoMethodId);
    }
}

void android_main(struct android_app* app) {
    ALOGV("----------------------------------------------------------------");
    ALOGV("VRMode android_app_entry()");
    ALOGV("VRMode    android_main()");

    // Make sure glue isn't stripped.
    app_dummy();

    ovrJava java;
    java.Vm = app->activity->vm;
    (*java.Vm).AttachCurrentThread(&java.Env, NULL);
    java.ActivityObject = app->activity->clazz;

    // Note that AttachCurrentThread will reset the thread name.
    prctl(PR_SET_NAME, (long)"OVR::Main", 0, 0, 0);

    const ovrInitParms initParms = vrapi_DefaultInitParms(&java);
    int32_t initResult = vrapi_Initialize(&initParms);
    if (initResult != VRAPI_INITIALIZE_SUCCESS) {
        ALOGV("VRMode android_main, initResult != VRAPI_INITIALIZE_SUCCESS");
        // If intialization failed, vrapi_* function calls will not be available.
        exit(0);
    }
    ALOGV("VRMode android_main, VRAPI_INITIALIZE_SUCCESS");
    ovrApp appState;
    ovrApp_Clear(&appState);
    appState.Java = java;

    ovrEgl_CreateContext(&appState.Egl, NULL);

    EglInitExtensions();

    GL(glDisable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB_EXT));

    appState.UseMultiview &= glExtensions.multi_view;

    ALOGV("AppState UseMultiview : %d", appState.UseMultiview);

    appState.CpuLevel = CPU_LEVEL;
    appState.GpuLevel = GPU_LEVEL;
    appState.MainThreadTid = gettid();

#if MULTI_THREADED
    ovrRenderThread_Create(
        &appState.RenderThread, &appState.Java, &appState.Egl, appState.UseMultiview);
    // Also set the renderer thread to SCHED_FIFO.
    appState.RenderThreadTid = ovrRenderThread_GetTid(&appState.RenderThread);
#else
    ovrRenderer_Create(&appState.Renderer, &java, appState.UseMultiview);
#endif

    app->userData = &appState;
    app->onAppCmd = app_handle_cmd;

    const double startTime = GetTimeInSeconds();

    int whileFlag = true;
    while (whileFlag) {

        // Read all pending events.
        for (;;) {
            int events;
            struct android_poll_source* source;
            const int timeoutMilliseconds =
                (appState.Ovr == NULL && app->destroyRequested == 0) ? -1 : 0;
            if (ALooper_pollAll(timeoutMilliseconds, NULL, &events, (void**)&source) < 0) {
                break;
            }

            // Process this event.
            if (source != NULL) {
                source->process(app, source);
            }

            ovrApp_HandleVrModeChanges(&appState);
            if (app->window != 0) {
                ALOGV("VRMode app->window != 0, app->window : %p", app->window);
                whileFlag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // make call back to your java code.
    callback(app);
}
```

Here is the CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(VRWorld)

set(CPP_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main)

add_library(vrworld SHARED
        ${CPP_SOURCE_DIR}/VRWorld_NativeActivity.cpp
    )

set(ANDROID_NDK /Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/25.2.9519653)

add_library(native_app_glue STATIC
        ${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/android/native_app_glue/android_native_app_glue.c
        )

target_include_directories(vrworld PRIVATE
    ${CPP_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    )

# Link any required libraries here

find_library(log-lib log)
target_link_libraries(vrworld
        ${log-lib}
        android
        native_app_glue
        EGL
        GLESv3
        vrapi
        )
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Wall")

include_directories(${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/android/native_app_glue)
include_directories(${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/android/cpufeatures)
```

For the rest of the code, check VrCubeWorld_NativeActivity sample app from https://developer.oculus.com/downloads/package/oculus-mobile-sdk/

Comment: That sure is a lot of C code.  Do you know which aspect enables switching between VR and 2D that could be adapted to other programming languages (specifically OpenXR/Rust) ?

Answer (score 0):

The key to unlocking this functionality is the `com.oculus.intent.category.2D` intent category. My exploration on GitHub using this keyword yielded just two results. Notably, one of these is a hybrid application that seamlessly integrates 2D and 3D environments, known as [CitraVR](https://github.com/amwatson/CitraVR).

To effectively implement this feature, it's crucial to set up both the VR and 2D Activities accurately within your application's `AndroidManifest.xml` file. You can find the specific configuration details in the [`AndroidManifest.xml`](https://github.com/amwatson/CitraVR/blob/master/src/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) of CitraVR, which serves as an excellent reference point.